# Includes vs Joins Activerecord query example. Also refactoring. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: activerecord

Currently my controller looks like this:

```
def index
    if params[:activity]
      @trips = Trip.joins(:categories).where("categories.slug = ?", params[:activity])
    elsif params[:location]
      @trips = Trip.joins(:categories).where("categories.slug = ?", params[:location])
    else
      @trips = Trip.includes(:categories).all
    end
end
```

Because I want eager loading and since I am doing a lot of trip.categories calls in the index view, I want to use includes. But I think my syntax is wrong.

```
def index
    if params[:activity]
      @trips = Trip.includes(:categories).where("categories.slug = ?", params[:activity])
    elsif params[:location]
      @trips = Trip.includes(:categories).where("categories.slug = ?", params[:location])
    else
      @trips = Trip.includes(:categories).all
    end
end
```

This seems to be throwing an error in the view:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories"
LINE 1: SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE (categories.slug = 'hiki...
                                             ^
: SELECT "trips".* FROM "trips" WHERE (categories.slug = 'hiking')):
    12:     </tr>
    13:   </thead>
    14:   <tbody>
    15:     <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
    16:       <tr>
    17:         <td><%= trip.upvotes%></td>
    18:         <td><%= link_to "#{trip.title}", trip_path(trip.id) %></td>
  app/views/trips/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_trips_index_html_erb__1143926925325362083_70272895749760'
```

Anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use both `includes` and `joins`. `joins` to limit your result and `includes` to avoid N + 1 queries. My suggestion would be something like this.

```
def index
  @trips = Trip.includes(:categories).all
  slug = params[:activity] || params[:location]
  @trips = @trips.joins(:categories).where(categories: { slug: slug }) if slug
end
```

The nice thing about this is that if you want to add extra search criteria later on it is really easy to just ad a new line at the bottom.

If you would like to use this functionality anywhere else you might want to consider making it into scopes in the trip model.

Answer (score 0):

`includes` doesn't by default use joins at all. Active Record used to try and parse your conditions to see if you were doing anything that would require the joins version of include to be used but that was rather fragile and error-prone so it was deprecated and eventually removed.

Instead you must tell Active Record using the `references` method eg

```
Trip.includes(:categories).references(:categories).where("categories.slug =?", params[:location])
```

You can also explicitly request the joins based strategy by using `eager_load` instead of `includes`